# Can a web form access an IOS contacts notes section to autofill data?

Tags: ios

I know at this time you cannot create custom fields within an IOS contact, but is there a way to have web forms autofill with data in the notes section of an IOS contact?  Working on an app which will auto populate employee data to outside company webforms multiple times a day.